# Ignore case while grouping

Tags: jqgrid

Is there a way to tell the jqGrid to ignore the case while grouping? I don't want to change the data as some will be upper case, some lower case and others mixed case.

I'm using jqGrid 4.4.4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is good, but ... the current implementation of grouping in jqGrid allow grouping only **exact** values. I remember close requirements when one wanted to group by month instead by exact date.

After some analyse of the source code of jqGrid I hope that I found very simple and very flexible way to do more flexible grouping. I suggest to modify [the line](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.4.5/js/grid.grouping.js#L109)

```js
if( typeof v !== "object" && grp.lastvalues[i] !== v ) {
```

to

```js
if (typeof v !== "object" &&
        ($.isFunction(grp.isInTheSameGroup) ?
            !grp.isInTheSameGroup(grp.lastvalues[i], v) :
            grp.lastvalues[i] !== v)) {
```

After this one can define `isInTheSameGroup` function inside of `groupingView`:

```js
grouping: true,
groupingView: {
    ...
    groupField: ["name"], // the column by which we group
    isInTheSameGroup: function (x, y) {
        return String(x).toLowerCase() === String(y).toLowerCase();
    }
}
```

[The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/NotExactGrouping.htm) display the following results:

[image]

I used in the demo modified version of `jquery.jqGrid.src.js` of jqGrid 4.4.5. The version of `jquery.jqGrid.src.js` of jqGrid 4.4.4 modified in the same way you can find [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jquery.jqGrid-4.4.4/js/jquery.jqGrid.src-groupping.js).

I will post later my suggestion to trirand. I hope that the next version of jqGrid will contain the feature.

**UPDATED**: As promised, I posted [the corresponding feature request](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/feature-request/not-exact-grouping-case-insensitive-or-grouping-by-intervals-of-values/#p28707) to trirand.

**UPDATED 2**: I posted [the pull request](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/pull/452) with a little more changes of grouping module of jqGrid. [The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/NotExactGrouping1.htm) demonstrates how new features can be used. It uses 2-level grouping and displays the following results:

[image]

**UPDATED 3**: [The pull request](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/pull/452) which I sent to trirand is merged now to the main code of jqGrid. So the next version of jqGrid (after 4.4.5) will supports `isInTheSameGroup` and `formatDisplayField` arrays of callbacks inside of `groupingView`. If your case it would look like

```js
groupingView: {
    groupField: ['name'],
    formatDisplayField: [
        function (displayValue) { //, value, cm, index, grp) {
            return String(displayValue).toLowerCase();
        }
    ],
    groupColumnShow: [true],
    groupDataSorted: true,
    isInTheSameGroup: [
        function (x, y) {
            return String(x).toLowerCase() === String(y).toLowerCase();
        }
    ]
}
```

The callbacks `isInTheSameGroup[0]` and `formatDisplayField[0]` will be used by grouping by `groupField[0]`. Because jqGrid support multilevel grouping the `isInTheSameGrou` and `formatDisplayField` properties are arrays of callback functions instead of just callback function.

At the beginning of grouping **jqGrid sort** data by grouping column. One can use `sorttype` defined as function to customize the first step (see [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16221518/315935)). I don't though about the step during writing of your answer. Probably usage of `sorttype: function (cellvalue) {return String(cellvalue).toLowerCase();}` could already solve your problem.

Then the function `isInTheSameGroup[level]` will be used consequently to compare the value of grouping column from of previous row with the corresponding value of the current row. The function `isInTheSameGroup[level]` will be called with the values. If your callback returns `true` then the row will be grouped with the previous one.

The callback `formatDisplayField[level]` allows to customize the information displayed in the grouping header. In the example above I convert the data to low case.

Comment: Oleg, thank you very much for the detailed response and the feature request. I don't like forking code as it then becomes very hard to update to newer versions. Thus, I solved the problem by adding another hidden column with the data in uppercase and grouping by that column.

Comment: @JonasStawski: You are welcome! I understand your workaround and your point of view. Nevertheless I see the problem as common. I suggested before many features which are now the part of jqGrid and it helps other people. I hope that Tony (trirand) will do implement the feature which I suggested (it doesn't matter whether it will be implemented in the way in which I suggest it or in some other way).

Comment: I agree. Hopefully it does and I won't have to fork it and I can remove my hacks

Comment: @JonasStawski: The code of jqGrid on github is now changed to allows very flexible grouping. See **UPDATE 2** and **UPDATE 3** parts of my answer. Additionally I recommend you to take a look in [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16221518/315935). The trick with the usage of `sorttype` defined as function could be helpful for you.