# jqGrid drag and drop headings for grouping .... Group Name

Tags: jqgrid, grouping

I have setup drag and drop headings to group by the relevant column from [jQgrid Grouping Drag and Drop](http://jsfiddle.net/tpeczek/vRtKS/)

It works great however I am trying to display the column name before the value i.e.

```
Client : Test data data
Client : Test2 data data
```

I've been going around in circles if any one could help.
if i take the same code used for the dynamic group by which should be the (column Name)
I end up with The Column data not the column name.

```js
$('#' + gridId).jqGrid('groupingGroupBy', getheader());

function getheader() {
    var header = $('#groups ol li:not(.placeholder)').map(function () {
                      return $(this).attr('data-column');
                 }).get();
    return header;
}
```

if i use the same function in group text I get data not the column name.

I've come from C# and I am very new to jQuery.

If any one could help it would be greatly appreciated.

Kind Regards,
Ryan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all [the updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vRtKS/96/) provides the solution of your problem:

[image]

[Another demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/customGropingHeader.htm) contains simplified demo which demonstrates just how one could display the grouping header in the form `Column Header: Column data` in the grouping header instead of `Column data` used as default.

The main idea of the solution is the usage of `formatDisplayField` property of `groupingView` which I suggested originally in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16152739/315935). The current version of jqGrid support the option. If one would use for example the options

```js
grouping: true,
groupingView: {
    groupField: ["name", "invdate"],
    groupColumnShow: [false, false],
    formatDisplayField: [
        customFormatDisplayField,
        customFormatDisplayField
    ]
}
```

where `customFormatDisplayField` callback function are defined as

```js
var customFormatDisplayField = function (displayValue, value, colModel) {
    return colModel.name + ": " + displayValue;
}
```

will display almost the results which you need, but it will uses `name` property of `colModel` instead of the corresponding name from `colNames`. To makes the final solution one use another implementation of `customFormatDisplayField`:

```js
var getColumnHeaderByName = function (colName) {
        var $self = $(this),
            colNames = $self.jqGrid("getGridParam", "colNames"),
            colModel = $self.jqGrid("getGridParam", "colModel"),
            cColumns = colModel.length,
            iCol;
        for (iCol = 0; iCol < cColumns; iCol++) {
            if (colModel[iCol].name === colName) {
                return colNames[iCol];
            }
        }
    },
    customFormatDisplayField = function (displayValue, value, colModel, index, grp) {
        return getColumnHeaderByName.call(this, colModel.name) + ": " + displayValue;
    };
```

Comment: Also remove a heading doesn't seem to work it also makes place holder disappear if you remove all the groups.  Any ideas?

Comment: @rize17: It was a small bug in the other part of the demo. [The demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vRtKS/96/) fixes the problem.

Comment: I have one last problem. I have a DateTime as a grouped column. In the previous source (My Post) it worked fine. The new source I'm having trouble with. The formater for the column is  "width: 100, sorttype: 'date', formatter: 'date', formatoptions: { newformat: 'd/m/y H:i' }".   The date is displayed as "03/07/14 09:22" in the column (as usual) but the header is "Date: /Date(1404372141000)/"     I could use  "if (colModel.name == "Date") {'convert displayValue'}" in customFormatDisplayField  but I don't know what how I convert 1404372141000 into  03/07/14 09:22. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: @rize17: You are welcome! Formatting of grouping header using the formatter of the corresponding grouping column is *new question*. Searching engine don't search in comments.

Comment: Thanks I will post it under a new Question