# JqGrid - Using formatDisplayField Option

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I'm with a problem using jqgrid with some options, better that write is show you an image:
[image: jQGrid]

So, when I'm construction the table body (with ajax call) I'm passing an hidden field. When something is grouped, I want to show that hidden field where 'undefined' word is (group title).

Is there any solution using `formatDisplayField`?

What I have is something like:

```
groupingView : {
                    groupField : ['cpv'],
                    groupCollapse : true,
                    groupOrder: ['desc'],
                    plusicon: 'ui-icon-circle-plus',
                    minusicon: 'ui-icon-circle-minus',
                    formatDisplayField: [
                    function (value) { // Should be cpv_parent (hidden by default but sent to jggrid when instantiate)
console.log(value); // Contain CPV Grouped
console.log($(this)); // Contain [table#ajaxTable.ajaxTable.ui-jqgrid-btable, context: table#ajaxTable.ajaxTable.ui-jqgrid-btable, constructor: function, init: function, selector: "", jquery: "1.7.2"…]
                        //return String(displayValue).substring(0, 5);
                    }
                    ],
                    isInTheSameGroup: function (x, y) {
                        return String(x).substring(0, 5) === String(y).substring(0, 5);
                    }
                }
```

**EDIT**
As required, heres a sample data form what i'm using (from last try (using userData)):

```
{"total":1,"page":1,"totalrecords":3,"userdata":{"98513295":"98000000-3"},"rows":[{"tipoConcurso":"Ajuste Directo (Regime Geral)","createdOn":"2014-04-23 16:19:56","valor":15000,"cpv":98513295,"cpvParent":"98000000-3"},{"tipoConcurso":"Ajuste Directo (Regime Geral)","createdOn":"2013-10-01 16:05:08","valor":15000,"cpv":98513295,"cpvParent":"98000000-3"},{"tipoConcurso":"Ajuste Directo (Regime Geral)","createdOn":"2013-09-03 17:34:39","valor":15000,"cpv":98513295,"cpvParent":"98000000-3"}]}
```

Thanks @Oleg :)

Thank you all in advance :)

Regards,
Marcelo

Comment: could you provide the demo with the test data (3 rows - one group) which reproduce the problem. It's unclues for me for example whether one have the same `ajaxTable_cpvParant` value in all rows on the group. I suppose that placing the information as hidden column is the wrong way and it would be better to post the information separately as `userdata` for example. It's difficult to understand the problem without the demo.

Comment: Look at [the demo](http://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/78m7jdaz/3/). Probably it do already close things to what you need. It uses one more approach in usage of `summaryType` as function in the grouping column. It uses additionally `userdata` to provides additional information like youth from `ajaxTable_cpvParant`. It loads the data via Ajax like you do. The `serverResponse` is the response from the server.

Comment: The same demo, but using free jqGrid looks as http://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/78m7jdaz/4/

Comment: Thanks @Oleg. And how to apply that to `groupingView : { groupText: // HERE }`
I can't get there :(

Comment: `groupText` could be callback function in [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid). One can use `formatDisplayField` as function. I asked you to provide simple test data and test jqGrid with grouping. I would modify it to show how to implement the requirements.

Comment: Hello @Oleg, I have provide a sample data. Thank you so much for your help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a little difficult to understand your question because you display some abstract numbers only. I understand you so. You make grouping by `cpv` filed, but you need to display another field `cpvParent` which can be get based on the `cpv` value. One need just to have a map which get `cpvParent` from `cpv`. I don't recommend to add any hidden columns which are more expensive.

So I suggest that you change the data

```json
{
    "total": 1,
    "page": 1,
    "totalrecords": 3,
    "rows": [
        {
            "tipoConcurso": "Ajuste Directo (Regime Geral)",
            "createdOn": "2014-04-23 16:19:56",
            "valor": 15000,
            "cpv": 98513295,
            "cpvParent": "98000000-3"
        },
        {
            "tipoConcurso": "Ajuste Directo (Regime Geral)",
            "createdOn": "2013-10-01 16:05:08",
            "valor": 15000,
            "cpv": 98513295,
            "cpvParent": "98000000-3"
        },
        {
            "tipoConcurso": "Ajuste Directo (Regime Geral)",
            "createdOn": "2013-09-03 17:34:39",
            "valor": 15000,
            "cpv": 98513295,
            "cpvParent": "98000000-3"
        }
    ]
}
```

to the following:

```json
{
    "total": 1,
    "page": 1,
    "totalrecords": 3,
    "userdata": {
        "98513295": "98000000-3",
        "97123456": "97000000-2"
    }
    "rows": [
        {
            "tipoConcurso": "Ajuste Directo (Regime Geral)",
            "createdOn": "2014-04-23 16:19:56",
            "valor": 15000,
            "cpv": 97123456,
            "cpvParent": "98000000-3"
        },
        {
            "tipoConcurso": "Ajuste Directo (Regime Geral)",
            "createdOn": "2013-10-01 16:05:08",
            "valor": 15000,
            "cpv": 98513295
        },
        {
            "tipoConcurso": "Ajuste Directo (Regime Geral)",
            "createdOn": "2013-09-03 17:34:39",
            "valor": 15000,
            "cpv": 98513295
        }
    ]
}
```

Inside of `formatDisplayField` callback you can get `userData` parameter (the name of parameter is `userData`, but the JSON data have to have `userdata` in other case). Now the `userData[value]` will get you `"98000000-3"` by key `"98513295"`:

```js
groupingView: {
    groupField: ["cpv"],
    ...
    formatDisplayField: [
        function (value) {
            var userData = $(this).jqGrid("getGridParam", "userData");
            return userData[value];
        }
    ]
}
```

Such way will work quickly and you need just prepare the data on the server side in the above format.

Comment: Hi @Oleg, good morning! Yo uhave understand well my example, I will try it right now. But if you see, in my last attempt, I have already the correct data retrieve form server :)
Have tryied now and yes, it's working and now I understand must better how this works :)
Thank you so much for your help :)